Log4Net gives configuration error after .NET 8 update
I have updated my projects solution to .NET 8.
After doing so, I am now receiving error logs related to log4net in my Azure AI:

log4net: ERROR failed to find configuration section 'log4net' in the application's .config file. Check your .config file for the  and  elements. The configuration section should look like: <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />

I have not made modifications to the way I am configuring log4net - that is done programmatically, in LogHelper.cs I don't have any .config files
I've tried by adding a log4net.config and modifying my program.cs
var logRepository = LogManager.GetRepository(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());
XmlConfigurator.Configure(logRepository, new FileInfo("log4net.config"));

LogHelper.InitLog4Net();

The error is still received on AI. Something different should be made that I've now switched to .NET 8?

I’d ensure that the working directory is whatever you expect

You need a .config file for Log4Net to work. For example:
log4net.config
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="C:\Temp\Logs.log" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <maximumFileSize value="10000KB" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    </root>
</log4net>

I configured Log4Net in the Program.cs the following way:
builder.Logging.AddLog4Net(builder.Configuration.GetRequiredSection("Log4NetCore:Log4NetConfigFileName").Value);

Im taking the value of the .config file name from the Appsettings, so I can configure Log4Net differently for each environment.
appsettings.json
"Log4NetCore": {
  "Log4NetConfigFileName": "log4net.config"
}


I always had a  .config file. Still got problems after the .NET 8. i also noted that log4net uses an outdated .NET Standard 2.0.
